# DependencyProperty only binds sometimes and is reported as a missing property in the designer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I have a very strange problem with a user control's dependency properties.

It compiles, but a text appears in expected way. The color property works for the first 2 uses (endColor and progressColor), but does work in the text's foreground color.

Even though it should apply the correct color, the value of endColor.Color, it simply returns black - the default value.

Although it compiles and should work, the designer reports: "it can't find the property and marks my XAML as invalid".

I have restarted VS and deleted the designer shadowcache, but to no avail.

I use it like this is in the main window:

```
<local:HoverButton x:Name="cancelButton" Text="Cancel" Color="Crimson" />
```

Here is my xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="gbtis.HoverButton" x:Name="hoverButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:gbtis"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Border x:Name="borderBox" BorderThickness="4" CornerRadius="2">
            <Border.BorderBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop x:Name="endColor" Color="{Binding Path=Color, ElementName=hoverButton, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Offset="0"/>

                    <GradientStop x:Name="progressColor" Color="{Binding Path=Color, ElementName=hoverButton, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop x:Name="progressBlack" Color="Black" Offset="1"/>

                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.BorderBrush>
            <Grid>
                <Viewbox>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBox"  Margin="2,0,2,0" 
                               Foreground="{Binding Color, ElementName=hoverButton, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                               Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=hoverButton, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </Viewbox>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And my control code:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Color", typeof(Color), typeof(HoverButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Colors.Black) { BindsTwoWayByDefault = true });
    public Color Color {
        get { return (Color)this.GetValue(ColorProperty); }
        set { SetValueDp(ColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void SetValueDp(DependencyProperty property, object value,
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] String p = null) {
        SetValue(property, value);
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

I removed the event I had used to try and force an update and gave the textbox a solidcolorbrush. Now the properties seem to work.

However... The designer still shows them as not recognized or innaccessible

Comment: Your SetValueDp method doesn't make sense. A dependency property does not need to fire a PropertyChanged event, because it has its own change notification mechanism. Besides that, the SetValueDp method may not even be called, because WPF may bypass the property setter, and directly call SetValue, e.g. when the property is set by a Binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the specified binding is not working is because you're binding `TextBlock.Foreground` property, which is of type `Brush`, to your `HoverButton.Color` property, which is of type `Color`, and the framework is not able to convert a `Color` to a `Brush`.

So in order to fix this you either need to provide a converter through `Binding.Converter` property to do the job, or provide a brush and make it use the value of the `HoverButton.Color`. In this case I think the brush you're looking for is a `SolidColorBrush`:

```
<TextBlock (...)>
    <TextBlock.Foreground>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color, ElementName=hoverButton, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </TextBlock.Foreground>
</TextBlock>
```

Note though that if you go with the second solution, making the binding `TwoWay` is pretty much pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Like clemens said a dependency property doesn't work like that.
You can use its "PropertyChangedCallback".

```
public Color Color {
    get { return (Color)this.GetValue(ColorProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ColorProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Color", typeof(Color), typeof(HoverButton), new PropertyMetadata(Colors.Black, PropertyChanged));

public static void PropertyChanged(DependencyObject dependency, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //some code
}
```

But this is only needed, if you want to do something when the property is changed, it isn't needed to notify the GUI.

By the way your datacontext should be something like that:

```
public HoverButton()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    (this.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;
}
```

This way your CodeBehind can bind to the UserControl and the UserControl inherits the DataContext from its parent.

EDIT:

Grx70 is right. The conversion isn't workig too.

http://blog.scottlogic.com/2010/07/09/a-universal-value-converter-for-wpf.html